# Converting contents of files called from another script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script called "concat" that takes files named in the command line and concatenates the contents of their files. I need to make a new script that calls "concat" and converts the contents to all uppercase or all lowercase depending on the command passed on the command line.

I have created the entire concat script and tested it. However I am trying to debug my new "concatconvert" script which calls the concat script. I can't get any output to print and am not sure why.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "Usage: concatconvert [-u|-l| FILE ... \nDescription: 
concatenates FILE(s) to standard output separating them with 
divider -----. Optional first argument -u or -l converts contents 
to uppercase or lowercase, respectively."
    exit 1
fi

option=$1
shift

echo $1

if [ $1 == "-u" ]; then
    echo $output
    output=$(bash concat $@)
    echo $output
elif [ $1 == "-l" ]; then
    echo $output
    output=$(bash concat $@)
    echo $output
fi
exit 0
```

I need the output to print the contents of the files passed in the command in either uppercase or lowercase, depending on the command passed in $1.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't get any output to print and am not sure why.

The reason is that in

```
if [ $1 == "-u" ]; then
```

and

```
elif [ $1 == "-l" ]; then
```

you should have used `$option` rather than `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tr` to convert case:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
-u)
    shift
    for file in "$@"
    do
        tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <"$file"
        echo -----
    done
    ;;
-l)
    shift
    for file in "$@"
    do
        tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <"$file"
        echo -----
    done
    ;;
*)
    echo 'Usage....'
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```